# Traducción al castellano de "scrapbook"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Tengo que traducir una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en mi compañía.

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo traducir la palabra "*scrapbook*"?

Se me ocurren: "borrador", "cuaderno de recortes". Pero no sé si suenan bien.

Comment: Deberías poner algo de contexto, ¿Dónde se va a usar esa palabra y a qué hace referencia exactamente?

Comment: Hace referencia a un scrapbook en un sitio donde publicas cosas que solo son visibles para ti. "Add post to scrapbook" "Añade la publicación a tu Scrapbook".

Comment: entonces parece que borrador estaría bien

Comment: Post es publicación en español. Para Scrapbook no hay traduccion literal.

Comment: también podrías usar álbum: *Añade una publicación en tu álbum*

Comment: Notas al margen se me ocurre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Creo que has acertado con <s>borrador</s> nota.

No se me ocurre una palabra que signifique "lugar en el que se guardan las notas", por lo que usaría la traducción que pongo a continuación.

Has puesto en un comentario el siguiente ejemplo:

> Add post to scrapbook

Yo esto lo traduciría como:

> Añadir [post] a notas

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo. Nota: La palabra `post` no existe en el español, pero igualmente es usada en las redes socials, es algo común. También cuando se habla de un post, se lo puede interpretar como una publicación en un foro, o una entrada en un borrador.

Comment: Al final decidí usar ```notas``` puesto que no se pueden hacer publicas y borrador parece que se pueden llegar a hacer publicas.

Comment: @Wawy Borrador no hace referencia a que se pueden hacer publicas. Igual Notas es correcto. Aunque es mas generico.

Comment: Borrador: 2.  ```m. Texto provisional susceptible de modificación y desarrollo.```
Mientras que nota: ```6. f. Mensaje breve escrito.```

Me gusta mas nota porque no implica que sea algo temporal

Comment: hmm, creo que tienes razón, aunque aplicaría la misma lógica (añadir a notas)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that @blonfu made the best suggestion in a comment

> álbum
>   Del lat. album 'encerado blanco'.
>   1. m. Libro en blanco, comúnmente apaisado, y encuadernado con más o menos lujo, cuyas hojas se llenan con breves composiciones literarias, sentencias, máximas, piezas de música, firmas, retratos, etc.
>   2. m. Libro en blanco de hojas dobles, con una o más aberturas de forma regular, a manera de marcos, para colocar en ellas fotografías, acuarelas, grabados, etc.
>   plus a couple of other defintions not relevant here

Source http://dle.rae.es/?id=1ZGwYyW

This is what the English word scrapbook means. However from the original question it seems that in the context of the OP's workplace it may mean something different